# How to stop Google's Media Player, if audio in app starts playing

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, avaudioplayer

I have to stop external media player if my app audio starts playing. In case of youtube, it stops automatically but google's media player, doesn't stops.

I have used following code.

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener audioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                    switch (focusChange) {
                        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                     if (TextToSpeechController.getMediaPlayerInstance().isPlaying()) {                                    TextToSpeechController.getMediaPlayerInstance().stop();}
                            break;                        
                }
            };        
            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

But it is stopping my other audio's as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(manager.isMusicActive())
 {
     // do something - or don't
 }
```